# Create two threads in python one to read and one to ask something

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I would like to know if there is how to create two threads, one to ask some number and another to show this number typed in parallel.

```
from threading import Thread

global result
result = None


class OutPut(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
      Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
      global result
      if result is not None:
          print('Number entered was: {}'.format(result))


class Write(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
      Thread.__init__(self);

    def run(self):
      global result
      user_write = True

      while user_write:
          num = int(input('Enter a number? '))
          result = num

          if num == 0:
              user_write = False


threadIO = Write()
threadOutPut = OutPut()

arrThread = [threadIO, threadOutPut]

for tH in arrThread:
  tH.start()

for t in arrThread:
  t.join()

print('===== THREADS OFF =====')
```

I was trying to do something with this code. The "thread" of asking until it works but showing what was typed doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I still could not pin down your exact requirements, but I think what you need is something like this...

```
import time
import readline
import thread
import sys

global num
num = None

def print_num():
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        sys.stdout.write('\r'+' '*(len(readline.get_line_buffer())+2)+'\r')
        global num
        if num:
            print("Writing ", num)
        sys.stdout.write('Enter number > ' + readline.get_line_buffer())
        sys.stdout.flush()

thread.Thread(target=print_num).start()

while True:
    num = input('Enter number > ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some changes to your `OutPut` thread to print each result one time and also exit when 0 is input. The important part is that the `OutPut` thread must keep looping to check `result`, then reset `result` after printing it.

In your original code, you might consider putting a print at the end of `OutPut`'s `run` function to see why the code doesn't work as you expected.

```py
from threading import Thread

global result
result = None


class OutPut(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global result
        while True: # Loop to check the result
            if result is not None:
                print("Number entered was: {}".format(result))
                if result == 0:
                    break  # if result is 0, break the loop
                result = None  # reset the result to None, so we don't print the same result again
        print("Thread finished")


class Write(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global result
        user_write = True

        while user_write:
            num = int(input("Enter a number? "))
            result = num

            if num == 0:
                user_write = False


threadIO = Write()
threadOutPut = OutPut()

arrThread = [threadIO, threadOutPut]

for tH in arrThread:
    tH.start()

for t in arrThread:
    t.join()

print("===== THREADS OFF =====")
```